# Laravel 5 validation: Unique-rule to check for emails with exceptions

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

For testing and support issues I´d like to allow one or two emails to be used multiple times in my users database. All other emails should be unique.
For example:

```
"email" => "required|email|unique:users,email,admin@test.de"
```

This isn´t working and I can´t use the id field for the exception because there will be multiple entries with the same email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [`sometimes`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

```
$whitelist = ['admin@test.de', 'foo@bar.com', 'etc@etc.com'];
$validator->sometimes('email', 'unique:users', function($input) use ($whitelist){
    return ! in_array($input->email, $whitelist);
});
```

Meaning if the email is not in the whitelist, the `unique` rule applies.

---

Inside a form request you can add stuff to the validator instance by overriding `getValidatorInstance()`:

```
protected getValidatorInstance(){
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $validator->sometimes(...);
    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: This looks good but how do I implement this when using form-request-validation?

Comment: but where do I call that method? When calling it with the constructor method I get a FatalErrorException.

Comment: You don't have to call it yourself. Laravel does that internally. You just have to override it in order to attach the sometimes rule to the validator.

Comment: ah now it´s working: Of course I had to fit the returning rule to     'email' => 'sometimes|required|email'

Answer (score 0):

Try below where XX is your test user id.

```
"email" => "required|email|unique:users,email,XX,id"
```

PS  You can also set it dynamically during runtime if you want to